# How to compare two nested dictionaries with the same keys and update values with a condition in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1 = {'Berlin': {'Boston' : 9, 'LA' : 7, 'Chicago' : 1},
      'Vienna': {'Boston' : 5, 'LA' : 2, 'Chicago' : 8}, 
      'London': {'Boston' : 8, 'LA' : 6, 'Chicago' : 5}}

d2 = {'Berlin': {'Boston' : 8, 'LA' : 9, 'Chicago' : 4},
      'Vienna': {'Boston' : 3, 'LA' : 1, 'Chicago' : 5}, 
      'London': {'Boston' : 5, 'LA' : 8, 'Chicago' : 8}}
```

I would like to update the values in d1 if the values in d2 smaller than in d1 to get a new dictionary d:

```
d = {'Berlin': {'Boston' : 8, 'LA' : 7, 'Chicago' : 1},
     'Vienna': {'Boston' : 3, 'LA' : 1, 'Chicago' : 5}, 
     'London': {'Boston' : 5, 'LA' : 6, 'Chicago' : 5}}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as per your requirement (take min of `dict` items by iterating them together via `zip` and re-combine as a `dict` again, put it as value with same `k` as the key again):

```
d1 = {'Berlin': {'Boston' : 9, 'LA' : 7, 'Chicago' : 1},
      'Vienna': {'Boston' : 5, 'LA' : 2, 'Chicago' : 8}, 
      'London': {'Boston' : 8, 'LA' : 6, 'Chicago' : 5}}

d2 = {'Berlin': {'Boston' : 8, 'LA' : 9, 'Chicago' : 4},
      'Vienna': {'Boston' : 3, 'LA' : 1, 'Chicago' : 5}, 
      'London': {'Boston' : 5, 'LA' : 8, 'Chicago' : 8}}

>>> {k: dict([min(i, j) for i, j in zip(d1[k].items(), d2[k].items())]) for k in d1.keys()}
{'Berlin': {'Boston': 8, 'LA': 7, 'Chicago': 1},
 'Vienna': {'Boston': 3, 'LA': 1, 'Chicago': 5},
 'London': {'Boston': 5, 'LA': 6, 'Chicago': 5}}
```

Comment: Instead of doing the min of the items, you can do the min of just the values instead. As a plus, that lets you use dict comp syntax, which is easier to read and shorter. `{k: {k1: min(d1[k][k1], d2[k][k1]) for k1 in d1[k]} for k in d1}`

Answer (score -1):

This data seems like it would be better as a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe) (basically a table) instead of a nested dict.

Once you create the input dataframes, you just need to combine them using a function that selects the minimal value for each cell. Here's a way to do that straight from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df_new = df1.combine(df2, np.minimum)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
         Berlin  Vienna  London
Boston        8       3       5
LA            7       1       6
Chicago       1       5       5
```

If you need to get it back to a dict, you can use [`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df_new.to_dict()
```

Which becomes:

```
{'Berlin': {'Boston': 8, 'LA': 7, 'Chicago': 1},
 'Vienna': {'Boston': 3, 'LA': 1, 'Chicago': 5},
 'London': {'Boston': 5, 'LA': 6, 'Chicago': 5}}
```

P.S. I'm not an expert at Pandas